# How to register Css of html page in wordpress theme

Tags: html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am new to wordpress development. I was trying to convert a responsive html page into wordpress theme but CSS for the html page is not working perfectly in wordpress theme. Please have a look at below images:

Html page header

[image]

wordpress theme header

[image]

I am not able to figure out that why the wordpress theme header is not same like the html page header while `Style.css` is same.
Please suggest to me how i can solve this issue.

Comment: In you header.php is there anything like this  ?<link href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />

Comment: yes , i have included style.css by above method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is all process of call WordPress directory images , styles or post etc please check it.

```
 default CSS call 
<link href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />

 <a href="php?page_id=318"><h6 class="add-to-cart"></h6></a>-------page call

  <?php get_header(); ?>---------------------------------------header show

  <?php get_sidebar(); ?>--------------------------------------to call slider.php

  <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar name  include ' ); ?>-----to show slider wigdts

  <?php dynamic_sidebar('New 1'); ?>---------------------------sidebar 

  <?php get_footer(); ?>---------------------------------------footer show

  <?php get_template_directory(); ?> --------------------------dirctory path

  <?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>------------------script path

  <?php the_title(''); ?>--------------------------------------title show

  <?php the_excerpt(''); ?>------------------------------------content show 

  <p><?php echo substr(get_the_excerpt(), 0,170); ?></p>------content LIMIT 

  <?php get_search_form(); ?>-----search 

  <?php the_permalink(''); ?>----------------------------------post ka link(like click on title of post and it show inside the post)

  <?php bloginfo('template_url');?>/images---------------------image path 



  <link href="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/css/global-style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">-- css path in header file

  <?php echo the_post_thumbnail(''); ?>------------------------image show
```

There are many more but list is too long it will help you to make static html to dynamic

Comment: i have already added <link href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
 in header but still i facing this issue

Comment: go to your header.php and change  to calling method of stylesheet one by one   

<link href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />  

instead of this code <?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>
 1 <?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>
 2 <?php bloginfo('template_url');?>
 3 <?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>

Comment: sir , i already added this on header.php to include style.css but same issue is appearing

Comment: read comment again also can you show me your website link .?  what code you have written in your single.php or page.php it should be copy past of index.php

Comment: it is in localhost , so i am not able to show you. sir could you please explain your comment ?  i am not able understand this .  please explain it sir

Comment: your css is working fine  you just need call wordpress menu in to your header and wp search instead of search html .

Comment: ok then why background images below to navigation bar are not in their layout

Comment: because WordPress classes going to match with your css and i know you will have use important in your css                                     first call wordpress menu in your header lets see what happen then use  your classes

Comment: hello sir , i have solved everything except search box . i am not able to create a dynamic search box . could you please help with a example or code ?

Comment: if you have search.php then you need to call search form instead of your static input in header .php  paste this code     <?php echo get_search_form();?>

Comment: i do not have search.php . please how can i code for search.php then implement of header.php

Comment: have you tried to use this code <?php echo get_search_form();?>  in your header.php instead of static search code ?

Comment: after that go to your theme directory and copy the search.php file of twentysixteen  theme and paste it in your custom theme directory   thats it

Comment: thanx sir got it . But now i am facing one issue that whenever i click on search button then layout of page become bad . why ?

Comment: because the classes going to use in your search.php file of twentysixteen theme .  so you need to use html and classed of your page.php into search.php  , page.php and srearch.php will be same with html and classes  just php code will different in both files .

Comment: sir i didnt find any classes which are different in page.php and search.php or i am not able for which classes you are talking about . kindly help sir

Answer (score 0):

on your `function.php`  find `wp_register_style` function

and you can add your custom stylesheet file there

```
wp_register_style('THEMENAME', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css', array(), '1.0', 'all');
wp_enqueue_style('THEMENAME');
```

Comment: wp_register_style is not in my fucntion.php file . could you please provide like how i can do this , because with above method i am getting fetal error. please help

Comment: so you cn creat it
--

function NAME()
{
wp_register_style('THEMENAME', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css', array(), '1.0', 'all');
    wp_enqueue_style('THEMENAME');
}

Comment: no . same issue is appearing. could you please provide me other option .

Comment: what is the name of your custom stylesheet file? is it in some directory? or in the main theme folder?

Comment: style.css is the name and it is in same file (wordpress folder) with header.php and footer.php

Comment: and did you change the "THEMENAME" with your theme name?

Comment: try to add
-->
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', YOUR_FUNCTION_NAME );
--
after the function

Comment: yes i have changed Twenty sixteen theme with my theme .

Comment: "try to add --> add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', YOUR_FUNCTION_NAME ); -- after the function –"                                         how i can add this . could you please provide with an example .?

Comment: in the functios.php, after the function that i told you to add--
add this line -->
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', YOUR_FUNCTION_NAME');

Comment: so mabe the problem is with the stylsheet, try to change something in the style.css and check if its changed, like the bg color

Comment: yes if i change border color then changes are happening. but why i am facing this issue ?

Comment: maybe have another css style that called to the theme, try to find it in the original theme

Comment: rtl.css is another css which is in folder and editor.css in css folder of theme. do i need to remove theme ?

Comment: can you send me link for your site? i want to take a look for the styles that called

Comment: hello sir , i have solved everything except search box . i am not able to create a dynamic search box . could you please help with a example or code ?